# modx php get current page name

Tags: php, modx

In ModX, I'm trying to make a simple redirect based on which page the user is on. On my site, I have a chunk with various links to pages such as "About Us", "Careers", etc. This chuck is used on all pages on the site.

My issue starts here - within the Careers page, there is a link to a new page which contains all available job postings. I would like to make it so that when the user is on the Careers page, clicking the link to the Careers page on the chunk will take them directly to the job posting page, rather than looping them right back to the Careers page.

The url to the careers page is in this format:

```
www.example.com/index.php?q=careers.html
```

So, my code in the chunk for if the user is on the Careers page, redirect to job listings:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "index.php?q=careers.html") {
      echo '<p><a href="www.joblistsite.com">Careers</a></p>';
    } 
    else {
      echo '<p><a href="index.php?q=careers.html">Careers</a></p>';
    }
?>
```

But this doesn't work. It continues to link back to the Careers page instead of the job listings page. I've tried using the page's ID, but that doesn't either. What should I use for the **if** statement to get the current page in ModX? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try echo'ing $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?

Comment: Have you tried using `http://www.` instead of just `www.`?

Comment: I don't have experience with modx, but the best option to determin this is to debug the $_SERVER variable and check the contents of the various 'keys' inside it; `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: when I echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], it just echos "/index.php"

Comment: @Fred that's just an example URL. My actual code has a full proper URL

Comment: @br14np got it. Cheers

Comment: @thaJeztah that helped a lot. I found the correct key and now it's working perfectly. That's a handy trick for future use. Thanks much

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll add it as an answer so that you can close the question and mark it 'answered'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with modx, but the best option to determin this is to debug the `$_SERVER` variable and check the contents of the various 'keys' inside it;

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3):

The above solutions would work (especially WayFinder) but what I would suggest is to use MODX built in functionality which allows you to specify page alias to generate SEO friendly urls. Such alias can be used to easily locate the current page.

Simple and yet effective solution is to use page alias and compare it to the current one:

```
$page_alias = $modx->resource->get('alias'); // get alias of the current page

if($page_alias == 'something'){
// do something
}
```

If you deal with multi-level pages you may want to get the resource parent to make the above work more efficently:

```
$parent = $modx->resource->get('parent');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're quite new to MODX. Generally, [Wayfinder](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Wayfinder) is used for building dynamic menus, avoiding the need for hard-coded solutions like what you're doing.

To get started:
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Wayfinder+Introductory+Examples

To switch the href attribute like you want to do, you can specify a different `&hereTpl` parameter which will be displayed for the menu item relating to the current page. The `www.joblistsite.com` url might be contained in a Template Variable set on each page.

Comment: You would also benefit from turning friendly urls on:  http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+Friendly+URLs